# GROUP BY Result does not return the Max() string

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am using recursion within a common table expression (CTE) to concatenate multiple rows.  The recursion works fine.  But in the `SELECT` statement after the CTE I want to return only the rows with the concatenated string.  But I use MAX(stringValue) it returns the shortest string.  When I use MIN(stringValue) it returns the correct (longest) string.  Why is that?
This is the data in the CTE when returning all of the rows:

```
Row     TableName       Script
1       Activity        This is a string that I created.
1       Table2          This is another string.
2       Table2          This is another string.  This is another string.
1       Table3          Test string.
2       Table3          Test string. Test string 2.
3       Table3          Test string.  Test string 2. Test string 3.
```

When I use this query to return only the rows with the MAX(Row):

```
SELECT MAX(Row) AS RowNumber, MAX(TableName) AS Tbl, MAX(Script)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY TableName
```

My Result is this:

```
Row     TableName       Script
1       Activity        This is a string that I created.
2       Table2          This is another string.
3       Table3          Test string.
```

The correct Row is returned but NOT the correct script.
When I using this query:

```
SELECT MAX(Row) AS RowNumber, MAX(Table) AS Tbl, MIN(Script)
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY TableName
```

I get the correct data, ie. the longest string.
Why is this?

I used this in another query and the correct string was returned, ie the longest string.

I am concerned that these results will be unpredictable and inconsistent.

**UPDATE**
I want to return these rows:

```
 Row    TableName       Script
    1       Activity        This is a string that I created.
    2       Table2          This is another string.  This is another string.
    3       Table3          Test string.  Test string 2. Test string 3.
```

Comment: Do you mean, if you use `MAX` it truncates string to first `.` and if you use `MIN`, it gives complete value?

Comment: No.  Max() returns the shortest string.  and Min() returns the longest.

Comment: Min/Max doesn't care about the length of the strings, it cares about alphabetical order.

Comment: OK.  That must be it.  So, is there a way to make sure I am returning the concatenated row?

Comment: It is because of the way characters sort. Look at the values from Table 3. Obviously Row 2 is > Row 1. But row 2 is also the "greatest" string because it sorts by each character position. the length has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If you need a certain row you would need to determine which row. In this case it sounds like length of the string. You could use ROW_NUMBER and order by LEN(Script)

Comment: Are you trying to do this: `MAX(LEN(column))` here?

Comment: so, use @DavidG suggestion; I just can't think you are going in the right way to extract something out of it using `MAX / Min`.

Comment: I updated my post to show you the rows that I want to return.  I use this type of query in a couple of places so I need to make sure it is consistent.

Comment: I don't want the length of the strings.  I want the longest strings that have been concatenated.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the longest string? If that isn't the case then you need explain WHY the certain values you want are correct. I can 2-3 ways to get those rows but I have no idea what your logic needs to be. It could be the longest value, it could the largest row value, it could be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `max()` should be returning the row that you want.  But, you can also get the latest version using:

```
select t.*
from (select cte.*, row_number() over (partition by table order by row desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns the row with the largest `row`.  You could also get the longest string by using `order by len(script) desc`.

I note that your code that doesn't work uses both `table` and `tablename`.  I'm not sure if that explains the unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I will try this.  The Table / TableName was a misprint that I will fix.

Comment: That worked like a charm!  Thanks so much...very clever, I must say!